# '404 Not Found' errors when upgrading to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, upgrade

I tried upgrading from 11.04 to 11.10 and failed:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates InRelease
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com oneiric InRelease
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates Release.gpg
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com oneiric Release.gpg
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates Release
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com oneiric Release
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/main armel Packages
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/restricted armel Packages
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/universe armel Packages
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/multiverse armel Packages
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com oneiric/main armel Packages
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted armel Packages
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe armel Packages
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse armel Packages
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com oneiric/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Translation-en
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  apt apt-utils aptitude bind9-host binutils ca-certificates console-setup cpp cpp-4.5 dnsutils g++ g++-4.5 gawk gcc gcc-4.5 gcc-4.5-base hostapd info iproute
  iputils-ping libbind9-60 libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev libcloog-ppl0 libcurl3-gnutls libcwidget3 libdns69 libept1 libgcc1 libgfortran3 libglib2.0-0
  libgmpxx4ldbl libgomp1 libisc62 libisccfg62 liblocale-gettext-perl liblwres60 libmpc2 libmpfr4 libncurses5 libncurses5-dev libncursesw5 libpam-modules
  libpam-modules-bin libplymouth2 libpython2.7 libreadline5 libreadline6 libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libsigc++-2.0-0c2a libstdc++6 libstdc++6-4.5-dev
  libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl libxapian22 mount ncurses-bin openssh-client openssh-server openssl perl perl-base perl-modules plymouth python
  python-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal tcpdump vim vim-common vim-runtime w3m wget wpasupplicant
The following packages will be upgraded:
  at autotools-dev base-files base-passwd bash bash-completion bsdmainutils bsdutils busybox-initramfs bzip2 chrony cpu-checker cron dash debconf debconf-i18n
  debianutils dhcp3-client dmsetup dnsmasq-base dosfstools dpkg eject file fuse-utils gdb git git-man gnupg gnupg-curl gpgv gpsd grep groff-base gzip hdparm hostname
  ifupdown im-switch initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin initscripts inputattach insserv install-info iputils-arping iputils-tracepath isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common
  isc-dhcp-server kbd keyboard-configuration klibc-utils less libacl1 libattr1 libblas-dev libblas3gf libblitz0-dev libblitz0ldbl libblkid1 libbluetooth3 libbsd0
  libbz2-1.0 libcap2 libck-connector0 libdb4.8 libdbus-1-3 libdevmapper1.02.1 libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau1a libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libedit2 libelf1 libelfg0
  libexpat1 libfuse2 libgc1c2 libgcrypt11 libgdbm3 libgeoip1 libgmp3c2 libgnutls26 libgpg-error0 libgpm2 libgps19 libgsl0-dev libgsl0ldbl libgssapi-krb5-2 libidn11
  libisccc60 libiw30 libjpeg62 libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1 libklibc libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 liblcms1 libldap-2.4-2 libmagic1 libnewt0.52 libnih-dbus1 libnih1 libnl1
  libpam-ck-connector libpam-runtime libpam0g libpaper-utils libpaper1 libparted0debian1 libpcap0.8 libpci3 libpciaccess0 libpcsclite1 libpipeline1 libplist1
  libpng12-0 libsctp1 libselinux1 libsepol1 libslang2 libsqlite3-0 libssl0.9.8 libtasn1-3 libts-0.0-0 libts-bin libudev0 libusb-0.1-4 libusb-1.0-0 libusbmuxd1
  libuuid1 libwrap0 libxml2 libxml2-utils libxslt1.1 linux-firmware linux-firmware-nonfree linux-libc-dev lksctp-tools locales lockfile-progs login logrotate lsb-base
  m4 make man-db mawk mlocate mobile-broadband-provider-info module-init-tools mountall mtr-tiny multiarch-support ncurses-base netbase netcat-openbsd ntpdate passwd
  pciutils pkg-config pm-utils policykit-desktop-privileges pppoeconf procps psmisc readline-common rsyslog rtkit screen sed shared-mime-info strace sudo sysv-rc
  sysvinit-utils tcpd timelimit tsconf tzdata ucf udev upstart usbmuxd usbutils util-linux uuid-runtime whiptail whois wireless-crda wireless-tools xkb-data xsltproc
  zip
196 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 78 not upgraded.
Need to get 63.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 11.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/main debianutils armel 4.0.2
  404  Not Found
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/main libudev0 armel 173-0ubuntu4.3
  404  Not Found
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/main module-init-tools armel 3.16-1ubuntu1
  404  Not Found
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/main initramfs-tools all 0.99ubuntu8
  404  Not Found
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/main initramfs-tools-bin armel 0.99ubuntu8
  404  Not Found
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/main debconf all 1.5.40ubuntu1
  404  Not Found
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/main libpam0g armel 1.1.3-2ubuntu2.1
  404  Not Found
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/main libselinux1 armel 2.0.98-1.1
  404  Not Found
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/main libpam-runtime all 1.1.3-2ubuntu2.1
  404  Not Found
...
```

That makes me wonder if this a temporary situation, or if I must do something about my repository sources:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric main restricted universe multiverse
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repository sources were wrong. Correction:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports oneiric main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports oneiric-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

I was fooled into thinking that `old-releases` would work, since it did when upgrading from 10.10 to 11.04:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main restricted universe multiverse
```

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction: [Ubuntu End of Life Upgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades#Requirements).